# How do relationships work in Views?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, users, nodes

This is related to my previous question, [How can I make a block that holds all the information about an articles author?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/how-can-i-make-a-block-that-holds-all-the-information-about-an-articles-author) I want to make a block that holds all the information about the user who authored the node. I started using Views to make the block, and found the field "Content: Uid" underneath which is described as:

> The user authoring the content. If you need more fields than the uid add the content: author relationship

I was wondering if this could help me to make this block as I've described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a relationship in the View definition (Third column of the view input form), and select the Content:author from the dialog, you have created a link in the view that exposes data regarding the author. This will give you access to more fields that can be displayed in your view.

Check out the video series, "Taming the Beast" at nodeone.se to get a better understanding of what Views can do.