# How to add custom user fields to the Author Pane

Tags: 7, entities, blocks, users

I have a custom field for all my users called "Twitter URL," I would like to add a link in the author pane that will go to the "Twitter URL that my users set.

I would like to add a tagg like:

```
<a href="<?php print $twitter_id; ?>">Twitter</a>
```

within the author pane block.

here is the author_pane.tpl.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Theme implementation to display information about a given user.

 * Since the user is the author of a post or of a profile page, the user is
 * referred to as "author" below.

 * Available variables (core modules):
 * - $account: The entire user object for the author.
 * - $picture: Themed user picture for the author. 
 *   See author-pane-user-picture.tpl.php.
 * - $account_name: Themed user name for the author.
 * - $account_id: User ID number for the author.
 *
 * - $joined: Date the post author joined the site. (Uses shortdate format)
 * - $joined_ago: Time since the author registered in the format "TIME ago"
 *
 * - $online_status_class: "author-offline" or "author-online".
 * - $online_status: Translated text "Online" or "Offline"
 * - $last_active: Time since author was last active. eg: "5 days 3 hours"
 *
 * - $contact: Linked translated text "Contact user".
 *
 * - $profile - Profile object from core Profile module.
 *     Usage: $profile['category']['field_name']['#value']
 *     Example: <?php print $profile['Personal info']['profile_name']['#value']; ?>

 * Available variables (contributed modules):
 * - $facebook_status: Status, including username, from the Facebook-style 
 *   Statuses module.
 * - $facebook_status_status: Status from the Facebook-style Statuses module.
 *
 * - $privatemsg: Linked translated text "Send private message" provided by
 *   the Privatemsg module.
 *
 * - $user_badges: Badges from User Badges module.
 *
 * - $userpoints_points: Author's total number of points from all categories.
 * - $userpoints_categories: Array holding each category and the points for 
 *   that category. Both provided by the User Points module.
 *
 * - $user_stats_posts: Number of posts from the User Stats module.
 * - $user_stats_ip: IP address from the User Stats module.
 *
 * - $user_title: Title from the User Titles module.
 * - $user_title_image: Image version of title from User Titles module. This is
 *   not shown by default. If you want to show images instead of titles, change
 *   all instances of the variable in the code below.
 *
 * - $og_groups: Linked list of Organic Groups that the author is a member of.
 *
 * - $location_user_location: User location as reported by the Location module.
 *
 * - $fasttoggle_block_author: Link to toggle the author blocked/unblocked.
 *
 * - $troll_ban_author: Link to ban author via the Troll module.

 * Not working as of this writing but kept for future compatability:
 * - $user_relationships_api: Linked text "Add to <relationship>" or 
 *   "Remove from <relationship>".
 * - $flag_friend: Linked text. Actual text depends on module settings.

 */
?>

<?php
  // This bit of debugging info will show the full path to and name of this
  // template file to make it easier to figure out which template is
  // controlling which author pane.
  if (!empty($show_template_location)) {
    print __FILE__;
  }
?>

<div class="author-pane">
 <div class="author-pane-inner">
    <?php /* General section */ ?>
    <div class="author-pane-section author-pane-general">
      <?php /* Account name */ ?>
      <div class="author-pane-line author-name">
        <?php print $account_name; ?>
      </div>

      <?php /* User picture / avatar (has div in variable) */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($picture)): ?>
        <?php print $picture; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Online status */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($online_status)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line <?php print $online_status_class ?>">
           <?php print $online_status; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Last active */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($last_active)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line">
           <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('Last seen'); ?>:</span> <?php print t('!time ago', array('!time' => $last_active)); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* User title */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($user_title)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-title">
          <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('Title'); ?>:</span> <?php print $user_title; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* User badges */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($user_badges)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-badges">
          <?php print $user_badges; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Location */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($location_user_location)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-location">
          <?php print $location_user_location;  ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Joined */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($joined)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-joined">
          <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('Joined'); ?>:</span> <?php print $joined; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Posts */ ?>
      <?php if (isset($user_stats_posts)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-posts">
          <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('Posts'); ?>:</span> <?php print $user_stats_posts; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Points */ ?>
      <?php if (isset($userpoints_points)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-points">
          <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('!Points', userpoints_translation()); ?></span>: <?php print $userpoints_points; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php /* Contact section */ ?>
    <div class="author-pane-section author-pane-contact">
      <?php /* Contact / Email */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($contact)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-pane-link-line author-contact">
          <?php print $contact; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Private message */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($privatemsg)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-pane-link-line author-privatemsg">
          <?php print $privatemsg; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* User relationships */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($user_relationships_api)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-pane-link-line author-user-relationship">
          <?php print $user_relationships_api; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php /* Flag friend */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($flag_friend)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-pane-link-line author-flag-friend">
          <?php print $flag_friend; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php /* Admin section */ ?>
    <div class="author-pane-section author-pane-admin">
      <?php /* IP */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($user_stats_ip)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-ip">
          <span class="author-pane-label"><?php print t('IP'); ?>:</span> <?php print $user_stats_ip; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

     <?php /* Fasttoggle block */ ?>
     <?php if (!empty($fasttoggle_block_author)): ?>
        <div class="author-fasttoggle-block"><?php print $fasttoggle_block_author; ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>

     <?php /* Troll ban */ ?>
      <?php if (!empty($troll_ban_author)): ?>
        <div class="author-pane-line author-troll-ban"><?php print $troll_ban_author; ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with wiews, ctools and quick tabs. click here to see the discution. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18992/display-terms-username-and-user-picture-in-a-view-block  |  http://drupal.org/node/1396322#comment-5441770

Comment: With this module you can create what you want in drupal. i created a block where are displayed user picture, username, post date of an article, tags, category, total result of views, facebook like button ... and you can put there many more custom fields. if you want to try, watch these videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjOG8dVcN4Y&feature=BFa&list=PL7E361A55994F1648&lf=plpp_video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `var_dump()` on `$account` and then just went in and found exactly where the variables I needed were stored within `$account`. I then just print them out with print inside the proper HTML tags I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer. [Display suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds) is the easiest way. 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19120/4067